# How does $(x^3-1)$ factor out? (With application to calculus)

Tags: calculus

So the problem is:

$f(x)=2x^5-5x^2+1$

1. Find critical numbers
2. determine intervals where function increases/decreases

I know you have to take the first derivative which is $10x^4-10x$

However, when you factor that out, you get $10x(x^3-1) = 10x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

How do you find the zeros for the $x^2+x+1$?

Comment: Quadratic formula, or complete the square. There aren't any real zeros, though.

Comment: so would the only zeros you would use for the critical numbers be 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over the reals, which means you can't factor it into lower degree polynomials with real coefficients. It has two zeros, but they are complex numbers, namely $-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ and $-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.

One way to be sure that a quadratic has no real solutions is by graphing it. If you graph $y=x^2+x+1$, you'll see that it has no $x$-intercept, so you won't be able to factor it without using complex numbers. For the kind of problem you're talking about, you won't be interested in complex solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 + x + 1$ has no real solutions. Most straightforward way to prove this is to show that the discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$ is less than $0$. Plugging in, $(1) - 4(1)(1) = -3 < 0$.

Or, since $x^2 + x + 1$ is a parabola facing upwards, we could show that $x^2 + x + 1 > 0 \quad \forall x$. We could do this in a variety of ways, one would be to find the minimum value and show it is greater than $0$. You may recall that the minimum is the vertex which is at $x = -\frac{b}{2a}$. So, $x = - \frac 12$ and plugging that into the equation we find this minimum leads to a $y$ value of $\frac 34 > 0$